# How do I add a like button on my website for a public facebook photo?

Tags: facebook, image

I'm trying to display this public picture:
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151366898025044&set=a.405657690043.186402.502750043&type=1&theater

Using the Like Button Plugin:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

But cant get it to work. Do I need to edit my URL in a certain way for it to work correctly?

The tool should display 21 likes when entering the URL.